# Xsl, Xpath Following Siblings foreach

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to create the following structure with XSL:

```
<div class="helloclass">C
<div class="hellomethod"><p>test</p></div>
<div class="hellomethod"><p>test</p></div>
</div>
<div class="helloclass">
</div>
```

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <hello id="C"></hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="C"></hello>
</xml>
```

With XSL and Xpath I tried the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="hello">
      <xsl:if test="current()[contains(@id,'C')]">
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling">
          <xsl:if test="current()[contains@id,'M']">
            <p>Test</p>
          </xsl:if> 
         </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:styleshet>
```

I have a flat xml structure. For this xml I want to create based on the id's a structure.

id="C" means that it should be transformed to <div class="helloclass" >
id="M" means that it should be transformed to <div class="hellomethod" >

My first goal is to show the text: "test" in the right nodes.

Also M should nested in C and not a be a sibling as in the xml.

The follwing Sequences can also appear:
CMMCCMMMC, or CCCCCCCCCCMM, OR CM, ... Basically I need a "generic" solution.

XLST 1.0 Processor only available.

Comment: Please explain the logic **in words**. -- Note also that the input is not well-formed XML (has no root element) which makes  difficult to write the XSLT as the context is unknown.

Comment: I tried to explain my problem. Basically I have trouble dealing with a flat "xml" structure.

Comment: Can there be two or more sequences e.g. CMMCCMMMC in the same input?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that, I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Edit: Can Only use XSLT 1 processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would be a trivial task in XSLT 2.0, it is far from being trivial if it is to be performed by an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Consider the following:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <hello id="C">A</hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="C">B</hello>
    <hello id="C">C</hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="M"></hello>
    <hello id="C">D</hello>
    <hello id="C">E</hello>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="method" match="hello[@id='M']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::hello[@id='C'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="hello[@id='C']">
            <div class="helloclass">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('method', generate-id())">
                    <div class="hellomethod">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<body>
   <div class="helloclass">A
      <div class="hellomethod">
         <p>test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hellomethod">
         <p>test</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="helloclass">B</div>
   <div class="helloclass">C
      <div class="hellomethod">
         <p>test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hellomethod">
         <p>test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hellomethod">
         <p>test</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="helloclass">D</div>
   <div class="helloclass">E</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Do you have any resources where I can learn that so if I have another complicated problem I can solve it by myself?

Comment: I am afraid I am not the right person to answer this.